# AndroidStudio Project Compilation Error: Can't download gradle 4.1.1 - Unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Tags: java, android, gradle

I'm completely new to programming and just set up AndroidStudio on Ubuntu inside a VirtualMachine.

I set up JDK and SDK, everything went fine - but when I tried to create my first project, the compilation fails immediately (see error message below).

I already tried:

- changing the gradle version in build.gradle
- changed the distributionURl in gradle-wrapper.properties to https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.4-all.zip
- exporting and importing the certificates from a browser
- setting 'Accept non-trusted certificates automatically' to true

Error message:

A problem occurred configuring root project 'HelloWorld'.

> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
> Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.1.
> Required by:
> project :
> > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.1.
> > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/4.1.1/gradle-4.1.1.pom'.
> > Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/4.1.1/gradle-4.1.1.pom'.
> > sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
> > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.1.
> > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/4.1.1/gradle-4.1.1.pom'.
> > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/4.1.1/gradle-4.1.1.pom'.
> > sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Comment: Have you tried playing around with the Java key-store? Are you on a personal device? If it's a work issued device, there could be some firewall rules & all sorts that could cause this kinda issue.

Comment: Hi, yes, it's a work issued device, so that might be the reason.. Is there a way to manually insert the gradle-4.1.1.pom somewhere? I was able to download the file by myself, I just don't know where to put it.

Comment: I won't make any recommendations on how you should resolve this. It's best checking with one of your seniors or a colleague in that case, as there may be an approved way to do it & it may vary from one company to the next.